# Python Selenium - Count number of items in listbox

Tags: python, selenium, listbox

I am trying to count the number of items in a list box on a webpage and then select multiple items from this list box. I can select the items fine I am just struggling to find out how to count the items in the list box.

see code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
```

... ...

```
accountListBox = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_accountItemsListBox"))
accountListBox.select_by_index(0)

print(len(accountListBox))
```

I have tried using len() which results in the error "TypeError: object of type 'Select' has no len()".

I have also tried accountListBox.size() and also removed the 'Select' from line 3 which also doesn't work.

Pretty new to this so would appreciate your feedback.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#filling-in-forms) a list of Select element's options can be obtained by saying `select.options`. In your particular case this would be `accountListBox.options`, and you need to call `len()` on *that*, and not on the `Select` instance itself:

```
print(len(accountListBox.options))
```

Or, if you only want to print a list of currently selected options:

```
print(len(accountListBox.all_selected_options))
```

Comment: This should nail the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `find_elements` by using some common selector for each listbox's items to find all of them, store the found elements into a variable, and use a native python's library to count them.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use Selenium along with Beautiful Soup. Beautiful Soup is a Python package for parsing HTML and XML documents.

With Beautiful Soup you can get the count of items in a list box in the following way:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS() # or webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://some-website.com/some-page/')

html = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
b = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
items = b.find_all('p', attrs={'id':'ctl00_MainContent_accountItemsListBox'})
print(len(items))
```

I assumed that the DOM element you want to find is a paragraph (`p` tag), but you can replace this with whatever element you need to find.